# DropDownList in a custom form control gives 'DropDownList' must be placed inside a form tag with runat=server,

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls, runatserver

We are using a custom form control in our application. When we try to use asp dropdownlist control inside this custom form control, I get this given exception. But, when I use asp literal control we don't get this error.

Please suggest if you can provide me any directions in which to look to fix this issue.

Comment: All asp controls are server side that is why you need to put them into  form tag with runat="server" to execute on server.  Please add form tag with <form runat="server"> to you html.

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you are trying to add a `DropDownList`, it must be adding it outside the from tag, but the asp dropdownlist requires a form tag with `runat="server"`, since it is a server side control.

On the other hand your `Literal` control is working because - A `Literal` Control represents HTML elements, text, and any other strings in an ASP.NET page that **do not require processing on the server**.

To prove this, just try adding this in a webform:-

```
<body>
<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" Text="Hello"></asp:Literal>  //Correct
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTest" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList> // Error
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    </form>
</body>
```

`Literal` control will not throw any error while `Dropdownlist` control will throw the error you have mentioned because it is outside the `form` tag.

Answer (score 0):

If you are experiencing this because you are trying to write a user control which is executed on the server and passed via a service / ajax, then you should be using `System.Web.UI.HtmlControls` instead of `System.Web.UI.WebControls`.

For example, in this case you can use `HtmlSelect` instead of the `DropDownList`.

HtmlControls do not require a form tag with the `runat=server` parameter; It does however mean that any events related to these controls have to be handled by the front end (ie. Javascript).